# The Homosexuality of Hitler(ism)

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Most anti-Nazi voices, instead of praising National Socialism for having sluiced out the stables of Weimar and reimposed a moral discipline on the German people, **allowed the lax reputation of Weimar to linger over Germany as a whole for the sake of British and American readers, and then developed that sense by building up the myth of Nazism itself as sexually perverse**.*

Source: http://blog.yalebooks.com/2017/11/10/the-homosexuality-of-hitlerism/

I'm at my wits' end with understanding the above sentence. Does the author want to say that anti-Nazi voices should have praised National Socialism because it destroyed the Weimar Republic and established the rule of moral discipline (sic)? Can you especially explain to me the bolded passage? Does it mean that due to anti-Nazi voices the Weimar republic was in the eyes of British and American readers seen despite its bad reputation as a good regime, unlike nazism which was sexually perverted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't say what they "should" have done. It only describes what they "did" do. It should, moreover, be read with an understanding of the beliefs of most people at that time. In the 1930s most people thought that being gay was "perverse", and it was illegal in the UK and USA. Most people in the 1930s would consider a ban on homosexuality to be a morally good thing.

Anti-Nazis (in the 1930s) did not praise Hitler.

In particular, they did not say "Hitler has made Germany moral again".

The text further implies that they did not criticise Hitler for oppressive and (and murderous) homophobic policies. This is perhaps less surprising, as most people would have been in favour of criminalising homosexuality.

The text refers to the lax laws on homosexuality in Weimar (at least they were lax in comparison to the law in Britain or America at the time) and says that Anti-nazis criticised Hitler by implying Germans in general and Hitler specifically were "sexually perverse". In the context of the 1930s, being gay was considered to be perverse by most people. So in the 1920s Germany had a reputation for "lax morals". 
Anti-nazis let the reputation remain (or "linger") instead of saying that under Hitler a very different policy towards homosexuality was being implemented. This influenced British and American opinions of Nazis. The text says that this was done on purpose. Perhaps they felt that if they had highlighted the change in policy towards homosexuality, it would have built support for Hitler.  (As an aside, anti-nazis like Churchill also didn't emphasise Hitler's antisemitism, believing that many in Britain would support Hitler for being antisemitic.)

The use of "linger" is somewhat figurative.  You might say, for example, "A smelly gas lingers over the city". You would mean that the gas remains in the air over the city.  The idea that the "reputation lingers over Germany" figuratively imagines reputation to be like a "smelly gas".

The lingering reputation for sexual freedom led to the belief in Britain and America that Nazis were perverts.

It doesn't say if they should have done this, it only says that they did.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. But I still do not understand this sentence: Most anti-Nazi voices (…) allowed the lax reputation of Weimar to linger over Germany as a whole for the sake of British and American readers.  "To linger over" means "pause or hold back in uncertainty or unwillingness" which does not make sense in the context.

Comment: I've added a paragraph to consider the use of "linger" in this context.